# Using threads in C on Windows. Simple Example?

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, semaphore

What do I need and how can I use threads in C on Windows Vista?

Could you please give me a simple code example?

Comment: While this may be a simple RTFM question, it isn't not a real question.  After all, there are several real answers already.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Here is the [MSDN sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682516(VS.85).aspx) on how to use CreateThread() on Windows.

The basic idea is you call CreateThread() and pass it a pointer to your thread function, which is what will be run on the target thread once it is created.

The simplest code to do it is:

```
#include <windows.h>

DWORD WINAPI ThreadFunc(void* data) {
  // Do stuff.  This will be the first function called on the new thread.
  // When this function returns, the thread goes away.  See MSDN for more details.
  return 0;
}

int main() {
  HANDLE thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadFunc, NULL, 0, NULL);
  if (thread) {
    // Optionally do stuff, such as wait on the thread.
  }
}
```

You also have the option of calling [SHCreateThread()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759869(VS.85).aspx)—same basic idea but will do some shell-type initialization for you if you ask it, such as initializing COM, etc.

Comment: Keep in mind, however, that if you're going to use the CRT in the new thread you may need to be extremely careful.
In MSVC, for example, you should use _beginthread/_beginthreadex and _endthread instead of the relative APIs, to let the CRT correctly allocate/deallocate its internal per-thread structures. I think that also in other CRTs it should go somehow like that.

Comment: Additionally you can use SHCreateThread() if you want it to initialize COM for you on the new thread, among other things.

Comment: This seems to be a C++ example (link).  Would this work for C as well?

Comment: Win32 is a C api, so, yes, it should work.

Comment: @MatteoItalia how do we join or detach a thread in c `windows`? is there a good tutorial on it?

Comment: @turmuka: handling a thread is slightly different on Win32 than with pthreads; the `HANDLE` you get is similar to the pthread id, once you are no longer interested in waiting for it or getting its exit code you have to call `CloseHandle` on it, so you may say that `CloseHandle` is similar to `pthread_detach`. `pthread_join` job is split between several calls - use `WaitForSingleObject` to wait for the thread end, `GetExitCodeThread` to get its exit code (if you care about it) and, as always, `CloseHandle` once you finished using the handle.

Comment: if you are interested, I have another question. thank you so much by the way. I always ended up finding stuff about *C++*. Please check this link. https://codeshare.io/21Dkdq I asked a question with a comment there

Comment: That's not a good forum for asking a question.  Please ask the question on StackOverflow and paste the code into your question.  And also look up "infinite loop" while you're at it.

Answer (score 3):

You would use the [CreateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682516(VS.85).aspx) function.

You mentioned semaphores as well.  For that you would use [CreateSemaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682438(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Atomic operations and mutexes are good.  I use CreateThread etc, not pthreads.

Comment: Is pthreads avail. on Windows and/or Visual Studio?

Comment: no pthreads are not directly avail. on Windows and/or Visual Studio. You may be able to use mingw and cygwin however.