# how to create thread in C?

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, console-application

I am using Visual studio in windows for developing C library. Can someone please provide me simple example of creating thread in windows console application and starting it. Thanks

Comment: Simply search it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682516.aspx

Comment: C don't have any thread ...its os has...you are looking for windows thread then upper link is good

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use threads in C on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981459/how-to-use-threads-in-c-on-windows)

Comment: Which compiler / libraries are you using?

Comment: These links may help you. **[Creating Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** **[Thread Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#thread_functions)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ and C doesn't have support for Threads.
You have to use Win32 APIs for threading support for which you can google,BING.

Answer (score 0):

For windows: Use [_beginthread and _beginthreadex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa246693(v=vs.60).aspx). CreateThread has problems with the CRT.

For unix: use [pthread_create](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/)