# How to use thread in windows kernel programming?

Tags: c, multithreading, driver

I need to create user timer and thread in windows kernel program. Anyone please give a clue that if the regular threading headers are applicable in this mode?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981459/how-to-use-threads-in-c-on-windows?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look into KMDF or WDM if you are using some old drivers.

For timers see this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550050(v=vs.85).aspx

And here are threads or work items:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551203(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing in kernel mode, then you need to take a look at the DDK, as the functions are quite different and more restrictive to use, than the user space versions.

So the short answer is, no, the regular libraries can not be used inside a driver.

You might take alook at [PsCreateSystemThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559932%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for threading, as this is something you will need.