# How to use Multithreading in C?

Tags: c

This is my first contact with c and Multithreading.

I look for an example how to use it in Basic.

This is what I want to to parallel:

## PseudoCode that should run on different Threads

## Code1

```c
int main(){

   int i =1000;

   while(i>0){
   i--;
   }
}
```

## Code2

```c
int main(){

   int x =0;

   if(i%5){
   x++;
   }
}
```

I also didn't know how to pass Objects, maybe someone can explaine this too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please use only **lowercase** in **C** to declaring variables and functions
>   as struct,typeof,sizeof,int,char,void,for,while,etc....

**EDIT**:
Sorry for not to understand "I thought you need help to do that code in C"

Now i know that you want **multi-threading** functions to do two jobs or more at the same time without waiting for other to finish.

Okay, to do that you have to

- include `pthread.h` which means **POSIX Thread**

> **Note**: you should notice from this name that this library for **Linux OS** only

and you compile it with gcc compiler

- declare variable `pthread` to for example: `tid` in your **main()** as the most popular name
- Create your function in `void *()` and type stuff whatever it does then create your thread in **main()** and assign it your function through that code:

  pthread_create(&tid, NULL, MyThread, NULL);

**pthread_create()** arguments:

1. A pointer to a `pthread_t` structure that we created to fill it with the upcoming arguments.
2. A pointer to a `pthread_attr_t` with **parameters** for the **thread**. You can safely just pass `NULL` most of the time.

> **Note**:        The `pthread_attr_t` > "arg 2" should be treated as opaque: any access to
>          the object other than via **pthreads** functions is nonportable and
>          produces undefined results.

3. Take the function that you created as thread and shall be with **no return** and
   points to >> `void`, that's why we created **void *()**

> **Note**: Type only the name of function without **()**, you will know why in the next argument

4. Here you passing your arguments to your function!, if there's no arguments just pass `NULL`

**Example Code**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
int i=0,x=0; //Initialize our variables
void *MyThread(void *ANYarg)  //arguments must be a pointers to point from `pthread_create` with `NULL` if no need
{
    while(1) //background thread
        {
            i++;
            x++;
        }
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    char *input;
    pthread_t tid; //Declare a thread
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, MyThread, NULL); //Create the thread
    while(1) //Printing thread , Uncover increamting of variables
        {
            scanf("%s",&input); //whenever you input a value
            printf("i: %d, x: %d\n",i,x);//will print the i,x values now
        }
    return 0;
}
```

> **Note**: You should at least create **one pointer variable** specifically to your thread function cause **fourth argument** of `pthread_create()` need **at least one** to pass the `NULL` value

You can wait for an thread to finish instead of doing work at the same time through that code line:

```
pthread_join(tid, NULL);
```

Should return `0` when **success**

**An Example**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
void *MyCoolthread(void *vargp)
{
    printf("Yes..see me printing success after 3 seconds \n");
    sleep(3);
    printf("Success! \n");
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t tid;
    printf("Hello, are you there? \n");
    sleep(1);
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, MyCoolthread, NULL);
    pthread_join(tid, NULL);    
    printf("Yup i see!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Try to comment `pthread_join(tid, NULL);` with `//` to see what happens

and to terminate your thread is through code line:

```
pthread_exit(&tid);
```

**Doesn't** return to its caller any value

**Edit**: I noticed now that you use windows so i advice you to dual boot with Ubuntu instead if you really interested in C

otherwise you can use multi-threading in `windows.h` header that called **winapi** library but i'm not expert in so you can find an [simple example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1981459/using-threads-in-c-on-windows-simple-example) and you should mentioned in your post that you want for windows by the way you can edit to improve it

I tried my best to get it clear, hope it helps.

Comment: Note: i see no need for using `i` or even increment it but it will be useful if you put it as an condition : `while(i<10){i++;stuff..}` to `limit` the number of inputs and exit `while-loop`

Comment: Okay, maybe my question was not asked that good.

But this is not what I'm looking for.

I would like to use multi threading, so I can do two things at the same time.

Comment: I didn't know that you mean multi-threading by the way I completely edited the answer ^^

Comment: Thx, this is very nice! :)